# What is wrong with my vhost file when trying to implement SSL on an Apache site?

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate, apache2

I have installed an SSL certificate on my linode server and changed the vhost file for my site as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysite.co.za.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/94762545.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/94762545.ca-bundle


    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.co.za
     ServerName mysite.co.za
     ServerAlias www.mysite.co.za
     DocumentRoot /home/public/www.mysite.co.za/public_html
     ErrorLog /home/public/www.mysite.co.za/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/public/www.mysite.co.za/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

WhenI test the certificate from this page: https://www.digicert.com/help/ all the tests return as okay, BUT when I try to navigate to the url of the site instead of showing the site, it is showing the default site on the server.

Nothing is being added to the Apache error logs that seems relevant. There is this, but it doesn't look like an error:

```
[Thu Mar 22 05:50:30.134162 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4899] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 22 05:50:30.134190 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4899] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

and nothing is being added to the site error logs at all.

The ouptut from "apache2ctl -S" is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  mysite.co.za (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mysite.co.za.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.mysite.co.za (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.mysite.co.za.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost test.mysite.co.za (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.mysite.co.za.conf:1)
                 alias www.test.mysite.co.za
         port 80 namevhost test.othersite.co.za (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.othersite.co.za.conf:1)
                 alias www.test.othersite.co.za
         port 80 namevhost othersite.co.za (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.othersite.co.za.conf:1)
                 alias www.othersite.co.za
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@tomatie:~#
```

Is there something wrong with the vhost file?

Comment: How you navigate to site?

Comment: As in do I navigate to https:// or "http://" ?